# Proxy authentication in CFSteam based connection (iOS)

Tags: ios, proxy, cfnetwork, cfstream, proxy-authentication

I have implemented CFStream based connection according to CFNetwork programming guide. How do I get credentials for authenticated proxy servers? Is there a way where I can get shared username and password stored by the system dialog, the dialog which is prompted when NSURLConnection is used in the same network.